# I'm curious What is wrong with my app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I copied this out of a book and I debugged it on Xcode to simulate it, test it.  I'm a Beginner now at app development and usually this site is really good at answering questions and figures out whats going on.

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [rootController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Xcode is saying 'rootController' undeclared. How do I fix that?

And here is a second question I have:

```
[self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
```

On that code on Xcode it is saying that the rootcontroller is undeclared.
How can I fix that?

Comment: For the first one, can you add you're header file code?  for the send, can you include the full function code?

Answer (score 1):

Are those lines of code in the same file/class?

Say they are both in a class called Demo.m, you will need to declare the variable rootController in Demo.h

```
UIViewController * rootController;
```